# MATLAB plot at t = 0, 0.001, 0.01, 1, and 10 on one plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'm solving for a time dependent pde. Currently, I am plotting all the times from 0 to 10 that are evenly spaced with 10 values. 
If I only wanted to plot t = 0, 0.001, 0.01, 1, and 10 on one plot, how would I go about doing that?

```
  function simple_time_dependent_pdepe
      clear all; close all; clc;
      %
      D_ij = 1*10^-6; %Diffusion coefficient D (3.0*10^-7 cm^2/s -> 30 um^2/s)
      L0 = 1; %c0 [nM]
      x_f =0.02; %Length of domain [um]
      maxt = 10; %Max simulation time [s]
      %
      m = 0; %Parameter corresponding to the symmetry of the problem
      x = linspace(0,x_f,100); %xmesh
      t = linspace(0,maxt,100); %tspan
      %
      sol = pdepe(m,@DiffusionPDEfun,@DiffusionICfun,@DiffusionBCfun,x,t,[]);
      u = sol;
      %
      % Plotting
      hold all
      for n = linspace(1,length(t),10)
          plot(x,sol(n,:),'LineWidth',2)
      end
  title('Time Dependent')
  xlabel('Distance (\mum)')
  ylabel('Concentration (nM)')
  axis([0 x_f 0 L0])
  %
  function [c,f,s] = DiffusionPDEfun(x,t,u,dudx)
      D = D_ij;
      %
      %Rate constants
      k_1 = 0.25;
      R_L = -k_1.*u;
      %
      % PDE
      c = 1;
      f = D_ij.*dudx;
      s = R_L;
  end
  %
  function u0 = DiffusionICfun(x)
      u0 = 0;
  end
  %
  function [pl,ql,pr,qr] = DiffusionBCfun(xl,ul,xr,ur,t)
      c0 = L0;
      pl = ul-c0;
      ql = 0;
      pr = 0;
      qr = 1;
  end
```

end

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: what is m represent?

Comment: What happens if you set t=[0,0.001,0.01,1,10]?